# How to track real time position using google map API?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am planning to implement a vehicle tracking system. Can anyone explain how do i track the position of an android device using Google maps API .. Also if it is not android device, how do i collect the live Geological position of a device (android/iPhone/windows) again only through Google maps API.

Can someone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps:-

1. You need to host a server which accepts latitude and longitude values seeded from android device
2. you have to use google maps API also in the same web server.
3. Develop an android application implementing location listener, create a server connection and provide your hosted webserver adress there. a page at your webserver must be codded to accept the latitude and longitude values from the http post method.
4. code should be written to store this values in database and retrive it from database and plot it in google map using plotters.
5. you can write programs in windows, ios device platforms the latitude and longitude data has to be sended as http post to your web server.
   Thanks.