# Google map api + node.js realtime backend + ios

Tags: ios, node.js, google-maps

I'm new google map, so im not really sure how to start. I have few questions that Im currently confused right. I'm trying to build an application similar like uber

1) Google maps comes with and SDK, and how exactly am i going to make it in real-time, for example there are two guys with GPS, how does Guy A can see Guy B moving in reatime, do i need to use node.js + socket.io to make it work? or the SDK itself already handled that.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, [Google Maps SDK for IOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro#introduction) automatically handles access to the Google Maps servers, map display, and response to user gestures such as clicks and drags.

Please note of the following when using the Google Maps SDK for iOS in your application:

- You need to comply with the Terms of Service and ensure that your app complies with applicable laws. Note that when using the SDK, your application name and version, authentication information and a cross-application anonymous identifier is automatically sent with each request.
- You must include the attribution text as part of a legal notices section in your application which can be obtained by making a call to `[GMSServices openSourceLicenseInfo]`.
- Developing an application with the SDK requires the following: (1) Xcode 6.3.0 or later. and (2) iOS SDK 8.0 or later.

And for the implementation part, this SO post - [how to track real time position using google map API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209536/how-to-track-real-time-position-using-google-map-api) gives out the steps needed which could help.